# Calculating Aspect using terrain(), shouldn't water be NAs or 0s?

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra

I am working with SRTM data (scene ID: n03_e036_1arc_v3) from USGS Earth Explorer. I plotted elevation, slope and aspect in R using the terrain function from the terra package. The first two look perfect, but for aspect I would rather expect it to calculate NAs for the large body water on the west, or some arbitrary number, like 0. Instead it create weird patterns, as you can see in the figure:

```
areaDEM <- raster('DEM/dem.tif')
areaDEM <- projectRaster(areaDEM, crs = crs)
area_dem <- focal(areaDEM, w = matrix(1,15,15), fun = mean, NAonly = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

slope <- terrain(area_dem, opt = 'slope', unit = 'degrees')  # calculate slope
aspect <- terrain(area_dem, opt = 'aspect', unit = 'degrees') # calculate aspect
```

[FIGURE 1: elevation, slope, and aspect (projection before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKUlT.jpg)

I thought right away the problem might be doing the projection step before calculating the slope and aspect. That indeed changes greatly the output, but there are still very weird patterns calculated for the lake:

```
areaDEM <- raster('DEM/dem.tif')
area_dem <- focal(areaDEM, w = matrix(1,15,15), fun = mean, NAonly = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)

slope <- terrain(area_dem, opt = 'slope', unit = 'degrees')  # calculate slope
aspect <- terrain(area_dem, opt = 'aspect', unit = 'degrees') # calculate aspect

# join elevation, slope and aspect into a single object

dem <- stack(area_dem, slope, aspect)
names(dem) <- c('elevation', 'slope', 'aspect')
dem <- projectRaster(dem, crs = crs)
```

[FIGURE 2: elevation, slope, and aspect (projection after)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDWM8.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Guess I solved it by changing the default neighbors. But I do not really understand why it did not work with the default, so if someone wants to give me their two cents I'd be thankful.

```
aspect <- terra::terrain(area_dem, 'aspect', neighbors = 4, unit = "degrees")
```

Now I get a nice plot with an arbitrary value for water (90 degrees). This is what is supposed to happen according to the documentation.

[As your can see here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIj0R.png)